# Should I always use navigation properties or use the .Where query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

This question is whether which approach is better or whether it's insignificant at all. So, say I have a class **Item** like so

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and the referenced one **Category**

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on a category, all items within that category should be outputted in a list, and so should do the categories of that item.

I could use something like

```cs
_context.Items.Where(c => c.Category.Id == id);
```

and remove the virtual member.
The reason why I ask this and why I "want" to remove that member is because when I use WebApi to get Json data of the Items table for the client it outputs something like this:

```js
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "String",
    "Category": [
        {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "CName",
        "Items": []
        }, 
        {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "CName",
        "Items": []
        }
    ]
}
```

So the only problem with having a navigation property for the Category model is that it will also send me this "Items": [] when I request a list of items.
It's not like it's affecting me or anything, so I want to know whether I should use the Navigation approach or the .Where approach. Or maybe there is some other way I should consider?

Comment: Personally I prefer to use the navigation properties in the query and project/select to either an anonymous class or a custom class that will be serialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use navigation properties. EF will be able to generate a far more efficient query than you (likely, at least). Its also *much* easier to read.

That said. Do *not* use your EF objects as data contracts. Running one through a serializer will, in the *best* case do what you have above, and in the common case cause a circular reference exception.

Your contracts should be defined separately so the circular references do not exist. Use `Select` to convert collections from the DB type to your API type.

Comment: So I should keep the property, but create another class to use for serialization? And should that class contain the reference to the Item (this would also be a transfer object)?

Comment: @E.Hoxha Yes. That is exactly the typical approach. Item would be another transfer object that would *not* have the nav property back to its parent (to prevent circular references)

Comment: A decent read here: http://broloco.blogspot.com/2009/02/sending-domain-objects-across-wire.html   When I do POCO first EF, I've been able to send those across the wire.  However, if the project is non POCO first EF , then I do as you suggest and create DTO's....that have a more viewmodel flavor to them.